# If $W(t), t \ge 0$ Wiener process, show $ W(\lambda t) $ Wiener process, $\lambda \gt 0$

Tags: stochastic-processes

As title says. Intuitively it seems clear it should be true from the definition of Wiener process since $\lambda t \ge 0$, i.e it should be the "same" process shifted $\lambda$ in time. But it doesn't feel a rigorous enough statement.

Comment: It's not the same process shifted by $\lambda$; it's the same process with time measured in different units (where the units-conversion is $\lambda$). If for the old process the units are weeks, and for the new one the units are days, then $\lambda = 7$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for taking the time to answer. : )